How to use Nuxt build project to my node express server
After building my Nuxt project, the dist folder generated on the client side contains both client and server subdirectories.
Unlike with a standard Vue.js app where I can simply copy the dist folder to the backend and use it directly with
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
the structure here seems different. How do I properly integrate this Nuxt dist folder with my Express backend?"
im expecting it sync with my nuxt project

Why are you using Nuxt + Express? Quite redundant and indeed more tricky to work with. We'll need to have more details too.

You could serve a build with express if you had SSG build, though a dedicated webserver like nginx would be more suitable. If you have SSR build (server subdir suggests that), you need to run nuxt server https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/deployment#entry-point .
